# Qt Get Label To Stay Certain % Off Of Bottom

Tags: c++, css, wpf, qt

I am making a math application that will be used by kids to learn basic math skills. So far I have the title label re-sizing, and staying a certain distance from the top, but since Qt's origin is in the top-left, I couldn't line up the bottom start button. Any help of suggestion are greatly appreciated, and thank you!

Here is how far the start label should be off of the bottom:

[image]

Here is what happens when I re-size too far widthwize:

[image]

Chalkboard.cpp:

```
#include "chalkboard.h"
#include "ui_chalkboard.h"

Chalkboard::Chalkboard(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Chalkboard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/chawp.ttf");
    family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
    chawp = family;
    setFont(chawp);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(100, 100, 100, 100);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    image = new QImage(":/images/depositphotos_40177799-Seamless-Chalkboard-Texture.jpg");
    brush = new QBrush(*image);
    ui->graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(*brush);

    titleEffect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
    titleEffect->setBlurRadius(10);
    titleEffect->setColor(QColor("#e0dbd1"));
    titleEffect->setXOffset(0);
    titleEffect->setYOffset(0);

    startEffect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
    startEffect->setBlurRadius(10);
    startEffect->setColor(QColor("#e0dbd1"));
    startEffect->setXOffset(0);
    startEffect->setYOffset(0);

    ui->labelTitle->setStyleSheet("color: #e0dbd1;font: url(:/font/chawp.ttf);");
    ui->labelStart->setStyleSheet("color: #e0dbd1;font: url(:/font/chawp.ttf);");
    ui->labelTitle->setGraphicsEffect(titleEffect);
    ui->labelStart->setGraphicsEffect(startEffect);
}

Chalkboard::~Chalkboard()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Chalkboard::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QFontMetrics temp(chawp);
    if (windowState() != Qt::WindowFullScreen)
    {
        setMaximumSize(1920, 1080);
    }

    QFont temp1(chawp);
    QFont temp2(chawp);
    temp1.setPixelSize(width()/10);
    temp2.setPixelSize(width()/15);

    ui->graphicsView->move(0, 0);
    ui->graphicsView->resize(width(), height());

    ui->labelTitle->resize(width(), height());
    ui->labelTitle->move(0, 15);
    ui->labelTitle->setFont(temp1);

    //My failed attempt at it:
    if (height()/5 < 75)
    {
        ui->labelStart->resize(width(), height());
        ui->labelStart->move(0, height() - (height() / 5));
        ui->labelStart->setFont(temp2);
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "chalkboard.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Chalkboard w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Chalkboard.h:

```
#ifndef CHALKBOARD_H
#define CHALKBOARD_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsDropShadowEffect>

namespace Ui {
class Chalkboard;
}

class Chalkboard : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Chalkboard(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Chalkboard();

public slots:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event);

private:
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * titleEffect;
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * startEffect;
    QFont chawp;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QString family;
    int id;
    QImage *image;
    QBrush *brush;
    Ui::Chalkboard *ui;
};

#endif // CHALKBOARD_H
```

Chalkboard.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Chalkboard</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Chalkboard">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>644</width>
    <height>468</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>644</width>
    <height>468</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Chalkboard</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>61</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="labelStart">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>290</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>131</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>35</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignTop</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="labelTitle">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>391</width>
      <height>151</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>50</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Chalkboard</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignTop</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset resource="resource.qrc">
      <normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-1.png</normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-1.png</iconset>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>444</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset resource="resource.qrc">
      <normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-2.png</normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-2.png</iconset>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="resource.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to use a normal layout on your form, then you do not have to do it manually? There are many options: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html
PS: I wanted to build your code but without the UI file it is a bit difficult...

Comment: Please, post the picture of how you want the GUI to look like.

Comment: @TheBadger I didn't want to do that, because in order to have my QGraphicsView as the background, I couldn't use a grid layout or something like that. I just added the UI file if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: @Tomas I just posted those images.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by simply setting the QLabel's Y-Axis to `(height()-(ui->pushButtonStart->height()))`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

1. Create a `QFrame` widget and put your labels and buttons inside, together with the necessary layouts and spacers.
2. In your resize event handler just set the proper width and height for this frame like you do for `QGraphicsView` (to occupy whole parent widget area).

I have modified your .ui file as a hint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Chalkboard</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Chalkboard">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>644</width>
    <height>468</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>644</width>
    <height>468</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Chalkboard</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>341</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>210</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>349</width>
      <height>401</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="labelTitle">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>50</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Chalkboard</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignTop</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>20</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="icon">
          <iconset>
           <normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-1.png</normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-1.png</iconset>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="icon">
          <iconset>
           <normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-2.png</normaloff>:/images/liberty-technology-arrow-2.png</iconset>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>20</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="labelStart">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>35</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Start</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignTop</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <zorder>graphicsView</zorder>
   <zorder>frame</zorder>
   <zorder>labelTitle</zorder>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="resource.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```